# What data set option could be attached to given data set to replace the DROP statement that generated the error in the log for the below?

Tags: sas

After a SAS program is submitted, the following is written to the SAS log:

```
105 data WORK.JANUARY;
106 set WORK.ALLYEAR(keep=Product Month Quantity Cost);
107 if Month='JAN' then output WORK.JANUARY;
108 Sales=Cost * Quantity;
109 drop=Month Quantity Cost;
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: !,
!!, , *, **, +, -,
, <=, <>, =, >, >=,
AND, EQ, GE, GT, IN, LE, LT, MAX, MIN, NE, NG, NL,
NOTIN, OR, ^=, |, ||, ~=.
110 run;
```

What data set option could be attached to WORK.JANUARY to replace the DROP statement that generated the error in the log?

```
A. (drop Month Quantity Cost)
B. (drop Month, Quantity, Cost)
C. (drop=Month, Quantity, Cost)
D. (drop=Month Quantity Cost)
```

Can some please tell if this question is complete to answer? I know the drop statement had generated the error because of incorrect syntax. So I marked the answer as option A. but it seems incorrect and the correct answer given is D.

Comment: Since SAS statements do not require `=`,  you'd go with A. The `drop`option requires the `=`, similar to the `keep` option specified by you in the `set` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Pankaj:

How is it not easy to read the question closely and the documentation on [Dropping, Keeping and Renaming Variables](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lrcon&docsetTarget=p10abuffsctmo1n1dp2gasb34p76.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en) ?

`drop=` is a data set option specified in parenthesis after a data set is indicated, such as *SET dataset-name(dataset-options)* or *DATA dataset-name(dataset-options)* .

`drop` is a DATA or PROC step statement that indicates individual or a [list of variables](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lrcon&docsetTarget=p0wphcpsfgx6o7n1sjtqzizp1n39.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en) to exclude from processing.  The items in a list of variables is separated by spaces, not commas.

The question asks what **data set option** can be used to replace the faulty drop statement, thus `D.`

`A.` would be incorrect because you would be using drop statement syntax in the code place where a data set option is supposed to be specified.